# Can I set the text color of a labelField without overiding paint in blackberry Java?

Tags: blackberry, text, colors, fonts

I know I can override paint to change the text color in a labelfield, but I was wondering if there is a command like `setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.WHITE));` only for the foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think without overriding paint method you can set the LabelField's text color. If you set the background of the labelField then it will effect on the labelField not on the labelfield's text. So for changing the color of the text you have to override the paint method of labelfield. Give the color you want to the text and labelField's text will get the color you defined to them.
Yes you can override `protected void applyTheme(Graphics g, boolean arg1)` to change the text color of the labelfield.

i think this may help you

Answer (score 6):

In override "**paint**" method also you have **g.setColor(color);** method;

You said "**without overiding paint**"; So I am not using the paint method here;

```
label=new LabelField("Change color", Field.FIELD_HCENTER)
{
protected void applyTheme(Graphics g, boolean arg1) 
{
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    super.applyTheme(g, arg1);
}
};
add(label);
```

Like this you can do; I am providing this because it is one way of set the Color to the LabelField;